# Flag if a column in Dataframe with different strings exist in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flags

I have a dataframe:

```
Number   Items
 1        1,3,7
 2        1,2,7
 3        4,5
 4        9
```

I need to flag if any of `Items` values exist in the `Number` column for each row.

Output should be:

```
Number   Items      Flag
 1        1,3,7      True
 2        1,2,7      True  
 3        4,5        False
 4        9          False
```

What I have tried is: `df['Flag'] = df.items.isin(df.Number)`

This works when there is just one value in the `Items` column. I need to account for multiple values so that `1,3,7` are check individually and not just as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `zip` and a list comprehension

```
df['Flag'] = [str(num) in lis for num, lis in zip(df.Number, df.Items)]
```

---

```
   Number  Items   Flag
0       1  1,3,7   True
1       2  1,2,7   True
2       3    4,5  False
3       4      9  False
```

Notice that his is a `O(N*max(I))` operation, which can get very slow as the number of rows `N` grows and as the list sizes `I` grow. Depending on how your data is structured, you probably would want to reconsider your data structures' design.

Answer (score 1):

We could use

```
df['Flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x['Number']) in x['Items'],axis = 1)
```

or

```
df['Flag'] = (df['Items'].str.split(',').explode()
                             .eq(df['Number']
                             .astype(str))
                             .any(level = 0) )
```

**Output**

```
   Number  Items   Flag
0       1  1,3,7   True
1       2  1,2,7   True
2       3    4,5  False
3       4      9  False
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do `split` with `isin`

```
df.Items.str.split(',', expand=True).isin(df.Number.astype(str)).any(1)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```